# 3D scatter plot with in Python extracted from Dates

Tags: python, matplotlib

### Question :

**Is there a way I can convert day to String  rather than decimal value? Similarly for Month.**

Note: I already visited [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54113067/3d-scatterplot-with-strings-in-python) ([3D Scatterplot with strings in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54113067/3d-scatterplot-with-strings-in-python)) answer which does not solve my question.

I am working on a self project where I am trying to create 3D chart for my commute from data I retrieved from my google activity.
For reference I am following this guide : https://nvbn.github.io/2018/05/01/commute/

I am able to create informative 2D chart based on **Month + Time** and **Day +Time** attributes however I wish to combine these 2 chart.

3D chart I want to create requires 3 attribute **Day** (Mon/Tue) , **Month** (Jan/Feb), **Time taken**.

Given that matplotlib does not support String values in charts right away I have used Number for Day (0-7) and Month (1-12). However graph seems bit obscure with decimal values for days. Looks like following
[image]

My current code looks like this, retrieving `weekday()` to get day number, and `month` for month.

```py
# How commute is calculated and grouped
import pandas as pd
#{...}
def get_commute_to_work():
#{...}
 yield Commute_to_work(pd.to_datetime(start.datetime), start.datetime, end.datetime, end.datetime - start.datetime)

#Now creating graph here

fig, ax = pyplot.subplots(subplot_kw={'projection': '3d'})
ax.grid()
ax.scatter([commute.day.weekday() for commute in normalised],
           [commute.day.month for commute in normalised],
           [commute.took.total_seconds() / 60 for commute in normalised])

ax.set(xlabel='Day',ylabel='Month' ,zlabel='commute (minutes)',
       title='Daily commute')
ax.legend()
pyplot.show()
```

nb. if you wish to gaze into detail of this code it's available on [github](https://github.com/milandesai47/py-commute-calculator/blob/commute-3d-dot-chart-by-day-month/commute.py) here

Comment: You say the linked answer does not solve your problem. The suggestion there is to set the tick labels on the axis. Have you really tried that? `ax.set([...], xticks=range(1, 6), xticklabels=["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri"])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this (I have not verified for the 3d plot though):

```py
x_tick_labels = ['Sun','Mon','Tue','Wed','Thurs', 'Fri', 'Sat']

# Set number of ticks for x-axis
x = np.linspace(1.0, 4.0, 7)  # Why you have 9 days in a week is beyond me
ax.set_xticks(x)
# Set ticks labels for x-axis
ax.set_xticklabels(x_ticks_labels, rotation='vertical', fontsize=18)
```

You can repeat a similar procedure for months.

The source for this answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43460149/6997665).

Comment: I will give it a go. "Why you have 9 days in a week is beyond me" - I wondered same however it's kind of scattered. 0.0 - 1.0 Monday, 1.0 - 2.0 Tuesday, 2.0 - 3.0 Wednesday, 3.0-4.0 Thursday, 4.0 - 5.0 is Friday - I don't know why tho